# MongoDB $lookup Objectid get empty array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and practice `aggregate` with `$lookup` in mongoose following document, And i met a question really confusing.

I have user Schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  userName: {type: String, index:{unique: true}},
  password: String,
  avatar: String
})
```

comment Schema

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
  post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'postModel'},
  author:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'userModel'},
  content: String,
  createTime: Date
})
```

and models `commentModel= mongoose.model('commentModel', commentSchema)`
`userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', userSchema)`
Then i do

```
commentModel.aggregate.([{$lookup: {
  from: 'userModel',
  localField: 'author',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'common'
}])
```

But i get empty common in the query. According to the data in db, I shouldn't get this result. After searching i still can not find what's the mistake.

Last but not least, I need to use `aggregate` method, so i have to  use `$lookup` on reference document, dose it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from` field in $lookup is the collection name, not a model variable name. So if you are initializing the model like this

```
db.model('User', userSchema)
```

then the lookup query should be

```
commentModel.aggregate([{$lookup: {
  from: 'users',
  localField: 'author',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'common'
}])
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer, I have edited my question, for short, I didn't mention the model  part , but i did create these models.

Comment: As per updated question, collection name should be `usermodels`. You can verify it by connecting directly to mongodb and `show collections`

Comment: Thanks  sidgate. you point out the problem, i connect mongo shell and use `usermodels` instead of `userModel`, it works!  But during my  early practice such as `populate with reference`, i take `userModel` and it does work as well.  Anyway, thank your answer, it prevents me from getting crazy :)  Have a nice day !