# Mongo $lookup return empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

When performing a $lookup on my schemas, it always return an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

**Result Collection**

```
const resultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  trial: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Trial',
    required: true
  }
});
```

---

**Trial Collection**

```
const trialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

---

**Aggregate**

```
Result.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'trial',
        localField: 'trial',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'x'
      }
    }
  ])
    .exec()
    .then(results => ({ results }))
```

"x" ends up being always an empty array in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok just found the answer right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45481516/3415561

The "from" field in lookup must be your collection name and not the model name. Therefore it's a plural word. 
Here it's

```
from: 'trials'
```

instead of

```
from: 'trial'
```

Comment: Also make sure that Field Type should be same.
Example:- String with string, ObjectId with ObjectId

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had mistakenly put a $ in front of the collection name:

```
{$lookup: {
  from: '$users', // <- incorrect
  foreignField: '_id',
  localField: 'userid',
  as: 'users'
}},
```

it needed to be

```
{$lookup: {
  from: 'users', // <- correct
  foreignField: '_id',
  localField: 'userid',
  as: 'users'
}},
```

Answer (score 0):

check collection name. In aggregate function 'trial' starts lowercase, in results collection 'Trial' starts uppercase

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Changed it to 'Trial' in the from field of the lookup, doesn't have any effect. Plus, the populate function works on these schemas so I guess/hope it was not the problem.

Comment: Look at single document in Result Collection via mongodb console. Maybe mongoose use weird formating

Comment: Tried to delete the collections, corrected every uppercase characters from every models, recreated every documents. Same result. Also tried to reproduce query in mongo console, same result...